# Nokogiri & returning all data between two tags

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm working on a project that scrapes the items from https://platinumgod.co.uk/ & I'm having a hard time accessing all the `<p>` tags between two elements.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li class="textbox" data-tid="42.5" data-cid="42" data-sid="263" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a>
        <div onclick="" class="item reb-itm-new re-itm263"></div>
        <span>
            <p class="item-title">Clear Rune</p>
            <p class="r-itemid">ItemID: 263</p>
            <p class="pickup">"Rune mimic"</p>
      <p class="quality">Quality: 2</p>
            <p>When used, copies the effect of the Rune or Soul stone you are holding (like the Blank Card)</p>
            <p>Drops a random rune on the floor when picked up</p>
            <p>The recharge time of this item depends on the Rune/Soul Stone held:</p>
            <p>1 room: Soul of Lazarus</p>
            <p>2 rooms: Rune of Ansuz, Rune of Berkano, Rune of Hagalaz, Soul of Cain</p>
            <p>3 rooms: Rune of Algiz, Blank Rune, Soul of Magdalene, Soul of Judas, Soul of ???, Soul of the Lost</p>
            <p>4 rooms: Rune of Ehwaz, Rune of Perthro, Black Rune, Soul of Isaac, Soul of Eve, Soul of Eden, Soul of the Forgotten, Soul of Jacob and Esau</p>
            <p>6 rooms: Rune of Dagaz, Soul of Samson, Soul of Azazel, Soul of Apollyon, Soul of Bethany</p>
            <p>12 rooms: Rune of Jera, Soul of Lilith, Soul of the Keeper</p>
            <ul>
                <p>Type: Active</p>
                <p>Recharge time: Varies</p>
                <p>Item Pool: Secret Room, Crane Game</p>
            </ul>
            <p class="tags">* Secret Room</p>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

What I'm trying to do is return all of the `<p>` tags between `<p class="quality">` (excluding this tag) & the first `<ul>`.

I've tried several solutions found on the forums & have only had partial success with using the following code that I found in one of the answers (not going to lie, I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on here).  The reason I'm iterating is because there are several items in the HTML that need scraped:

```
items = html.at(".repentanceitems-container").css("li.textbox").each do |item|
  use = item.xpath(".//a/span/p[5]/following-sibling::p[count(.//a/span/p[6]/preceding-sibling::p)= 
        count(.//a/span/p[6]/preceding-sibling::p)]")
  end
```

However this only returns the first `<p>` tag after `<p class="quality">`.  I'm sure it's probably something simple causing it since I don't understand the code.  I have also accessed the first `<p>` element I want to include & the `<ul>` where it needs to end but I'm not sure exactly how to use this info:

```
# First line of item use
start = item.xpath('.//a/span/p[5]')
# ul tag
ending = item.xpath('.//a/span/ul[1]')
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```rb
require "nokogiri"

html = '<li class="textbox" data-tid="42.5" data-cid="42" data-sid="263" style="display: inline-block;"> <a> <div onclick="" class="item reb-itm-new re-itm263"></div> <span> <p class="item-title">Clear Rune</p> <p class="r-itemid">ItemID: 263</p> <p class="pickup">"Rune mimic"</p> <p class="quality">Quality: 2</p> <p>When used, copies the effect of the Rune or Soul stone you are holding (like the Blank Card)</p> <p>Drops a random rune on the floor when picked up</p> <p>The recharge time of this item depends on the Rune/Soul Stone held:</p> <p>1 room: Soul of Lazarus</p> <p>2 rooms: Rune of Ansuz, Rune of Berkano, Rune of Hagalaz, Soul of Cain</p> <p>3 rooms: Rune of Algiz, Blank Rune, Soul of Magdalene, Soul of Judas, Soul of ???, Soul of the Lost</p> <p>4 rooms: Rune of Ehwaz, Rune of Perthro, Black Rune, Soul of Isaac, Soul of Eve, Soul of Eden, Soul of the Forgotten, Soul of Jacob and Esau</p> <p>6 rooms: Rune of Dagaz, Soul of Samson, Soul of Azazel, Soul of Apollyon, Soul of Bethany</p> <p>12 rooms: Rune of Jera, Soul of Lilith, Soul of the Keeper</p> <ul> <p>Type: Active</p> <p>Recharge time: Varies</p> <p>Item Pool: Secret Room, Crane Game</p> </ul> <p class="tags">* Secret Room</p> </span> </a> </li>'
puts Nokogiri::HTML(html).css(".quality ~ p:not(.tags)")[1..].map {|e| e.text}
```

The `~` syntax selects the current and further sibling elements, so I use a slice to skip the first element. I'm assuming `.tags` is the only other class to omit after `.quality`; if there are other elements besides this, you'll need to `:not` them as well, or manually detect and skip them in an `.each` loop, unless someone knows a cleverer trick.

Comment: Just ran this & it works PERFECTLY, exactly what I needed!  I didn't even think about just excluding the p.tags & using map.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [this draft tutorial for nokogiri.org](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri.org/issues/28) which explains a few ways to do this.

Adapting the third (and most generic) approach, here's some code that does what you want:

```rb
class CSSSection
  def self.item_section(item)
    document = item.document
    start_tag = item.at_css("p.quality")
    end_tag = item.at_css("ul")

    # grab siblings that follow the start tag
    following_siblings_query = "#{start_tag.path}/following-sibling::*"
    following_siblings = document.xpath(following_siblings_query)

    # grab siblings that precede the end tag
    preceding_siblings_query = "#{end_tag.path}/preceding-sibling::*"
    preceding_siblings = document.xpath(preceding_siblings_query)

    following_siblings & preceding_siblings # xpath intersection
  end
end

doc = Nokogiri::HTML4(html)
li_nodes = doc.css("li") # whatever the query is to get the relevant "li" elements

data = li_nodes.map do |li_node|
  CSSSection.item_section(li_node)
end

puts data.first
# => <p>When used, copies the effect of the Rune or Soul stone you are holding (like the Blank Card)</p>
#    <p>Drops a random rune on the floor when picked up</p>
#    <p>The recharge time of this item depends on the Rune/Soul Stone held:</p>
#    <p>1 room: Soul of Lazarus</p>
#    <p>2 rooms: Rune of Ansuz, Rune of Berkano, Rune of Hagalaz, Soul of Cain</p>
#    <p>3 rooms: Rune of Algiz, Blank Rune, Soul of Magdalene, Soul of Judas, Soul of ???, Soul of the Lost</p>
#    <p>4 rooms: Rune of Ehwaz, Rune of Perthro, Black Rune, Soul of Isaac, Soul of Eve, Soul of Eden, Soul of the Forgotten, Soul of Jacob and Esau</p>
#    <p>6 rooms: Rune of Dagaz, Soul of Samson, Soul of Azazel, Soul of Apollyon, Soul of Bethany</p>
#    <p>12 rooms: Rune of Jera, Soul of Lilith, Soul of the Keeper</p>
```